# Why the ref in react is null here?

Tags: reactjs, popmotion

I have been experimenting with popmotion pure, since animation will have to use "ref" i am using it.
Here, why the value of ref(number) is null.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  styler,
  tween,
  merge,
  action,
  easing
} from "popmotion";

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.count = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const number = this.count.current.querySelector('#count');
    const updateCounter = (v) => {
      console.log(v)
      return (number.innerHTML = v)
    }

    tween({
      from: 0,
      to: 300,
      flip: Infinity,
      duration: 4000
    }).start(updateCounter);
  }

  render() {

    return ( 
      <div>
        <p  ref={this.count} id='count'></p>
        <div id="ball"></div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Demo
```

It return error as `TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null`

However, if I use this document instead of null, it's working fine

```
 const number = document.querySelector('#count');
```

Can someone please guide me through.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit...!!!, I was also going to make that.

Comment: Without getting into the reasons not to do it this way, `this.count.current` is the equivalent of `document.querySelector('#count')`. You don't need `...current.querySelector('#count');`

Comment: Yes,i got it from the answer below, actually i was following a code where the person uses something like this.

Comment: ` const mouth = styler(this.catRef.current.querySelector("#Combined-Shape"));`

Comment: I believe that's grabbing a child of the ref with that ID

Comment: hmmmmm..maybe, i had to see this through, thanks for the answer though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
const number = this.count.current;
```

instead of

```
const number = this.count.current.querySelector('#count');
```

[See live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/hbv4b)

Comment: It solved it, yes, but i was following a code where the user uses something like this ` const mouth = styler(this.catRef.current.querySelector("#Combined-Shape"));`